# Knowing the result of a given limit, calculate the following after. What is its result?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So I know for sure that by resolving the following limit I will have that result.

$$ \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt[m]{x}-1}{x-1}=\frac{1}{m}$$

And now I have this:
$$ l=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(1-x)(1-\sqrt[3]{x})(1-\sqrt[5]x)...(1-\sqrt[n]{x})}{(1-x)^{n-1}}.$$
How can I resolve the last limit using the upper relation?

Comment: How many things do you multiply in the nominator? $n-1$ And what is the power of denominator? $n-1$ also

Comment: it jumps from 1 to 3 then to 5 etc. So There are (n+1)/2 factors in nominator.

Comment: No, square root of $2$, then square root of $3$, ..., square root of $n$. I understand the confusion, it's coming from the notational difference of square root of $2$

Comment: What happened to the $1-\sqrt[4]x$ factor?

Comment: it is not part of the row...neither is $$(1-\sqrt[2]{x})$$$$

Comment: But wait that makes the first term $1 - x$

Comment: @RobertMaracine But the first factor is $1-\sqrt[2]x$.

Comment: wait... i'm so dumb i can't belive it

Comment: @RobertMaracine  it happens

Comment: @RobertMaracine, So what is the numerator, say if $n=6$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your limit is equal to

$$ \lim_{x\to1} \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1-x} \cdot \lim_{x\to1} \frac{1-\sqrt[3]{x}}{1-x}\cdot\cdots\cdot\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1-\sqrt[n]{x}}{1-x} \cdot \lim_{x\to 1} \frac1{(1-x)^{n-1-\left\lceil\frac{n}2\right\rceil}} = 1\cdot\frac13 \cdot \frac15\cdots\frac1n \cdot +\infty = +\infty$$

Comment: Where does$$\frac1{(1-x)^{n-1-\lceil\frac n2\rceil}}$$come from?

Comment: yes, i did that too, but the examinator who gave me the problem said that the result is 1/n! .

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown There are $\lceil\frac n2\rceil$ terms in the numerator so I factored out $\lceil\frac n2\rceil$ copies of $1-x$.

Comment: @mechanodroid I saw $n-1$ terms in the (original) version of the question. But I haven't a clue how many there are now $\ddot\frown$.

Comment: @RobertMaracine the result can not be $\frac{1}{n!}$

Comment: yes i am sorry. My apologies!

Answer (score 2):

By the product rule,
$$l=\prod_{k=2}^n\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{\sqrt[k]x-1}{x-1}\right)
=\prod_{k=2}^n\cdots.$$

Comment: Numerator contains odd roots $1,3,5 \ldots n$

Comment: @AhmadBazzi No, it doesn't.

Comment: yes it does.., let me edit that so it's obvious

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown thank you for the advice and sorry for the misunderstanding!